# Unity3D Camera jittering when dragging

Tags: unity-game-engine, camera

I'm making a game in which I want to be able to drag the camera across the scene. I wrote the following code:

```
// When dragging
    if(TouchDetection.TouchDragging && IntroBusy == false)
    {
        if(DragActive == false)
        {
            DragStartPos = TouchDetection.TouchPositionWP;
            CameraStartPos = Camera.main.transform.position;
            DragActive = true;
            CameraFollowingPlayer = false;
        }

        Vector2 Temp = TouchDetection.TouchPositionWP - DragStartPos;
        Camera.main.transform.position = CameraStartPos - new Vector3(Temp.x, Temp.y, 0);
    }
    if(TouchDetection.TouchDragging == false)
    {
        DragActive = false;
    }
```

During a drag, however, the camera does move, but has a jitter while moving. The further away I drag, the bigger the jitter becomes.

I've spent hours searching for the problem, but have still not found any solution.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of points
1. It's good practice to move cameras in [LateUpdate](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.LateUpdate.html) rather than in Update. This allows the camera to render after all bodies have been moved.
2. Rather than setting the Transform.position directly, use [Vector3.MoveTowards](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.MoveTowards.html) or [Vector3.Lerp](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Lerp.html) to set your camera's position.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it.

I was calculating with the touchposition in world coordinates. Whenever the screen moved, the touchposition also moved in world coordinates even though you didn't drag your mouse/finger.

Now I calculate with the touchposition in screen coordinates, which don't change when the camera moves.